# Java Heap size error in Sqoop import

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

I have been trying to import data from MySQL database to Hive using Sqoop utility. I got the table created and I have given the fetch-size as low as 10. Everytime I run the command, I am getting Java Heap Size Error and the job gets killed after 4 attempts. How can I fix this.

My sqoop command is as follows :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://my_local_ip/mydatabase --fetch-size 10  --username root -P --table table_name --hive-import --compression-codec=snappy --as-parquetfile  -m 1
```

and I am getting :

```
16/08/29 07:06:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1472465929944_0013/
16/08/29 07:06:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1472465929944_0013
16/08/29 07:06:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1472465929944_0013 running in uber mode : false
16/08/29 07:06:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/29 07:07:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1472465929944_0013_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
16/08/29 07:07:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1472465929944_0013_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
16/08/29 07:07:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1472465929944_0013_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
16/08/29 07:08:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/08/29 07:08:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1472465929944_0013 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1472465929944_0013_m_000000
```

Comment: check if increasing mapper size i.e. `mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` helps. In my environment YARN container size limit is 32GB so I set `mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx30000m` and `mapreduce.map.memory.mb=32000` respectively.

Comment: I am using Cloudera only. Can you please let me know how can I make this configuration changes.

Comment: you need to do `sqoop import -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx30000m -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=32000 --connect jdbc:mysql://my_local_ip/mydatabase --fetch-size 10  --username root -P --table table_name --hive-import --compression-codec=snappy --as-parquetfile  -m 1` but do check YARN container max size. put a little less in `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and even lesser in `mapreduce.map.java.opts`.

Comment: I am getting this error while doing it  : `Error: Could not find or load main class ???-Xms268435456`

Comment: I am using the same command. Actually I am copying it from the comment and running it after changing the IP and DB name. Got the same error again,

Comment: Are you trying on Cloudera sandox?

Comment: @devツYes. I am. The Quickstart VM

Comment: How much RAM did u allocate to it?

Comment: @devツ I alocated 10GB

Comment: Did you get the same error when you tried without `--fetch-size <n>` tag in your command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122154/discussion-between-happy-coder-and-dev-).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sqoop import  -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx7200m -Dmapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=2400 --connect jdbc:mysql://local.ip/database_name --username root -P --hive-import --table table_name --as-parquetfile --warehouse-dir=/home/cloudera/hadoop --split-by 'id' -m 100
```

Initially, I have been using 10 mappers to process 10 million records and each chunk has a size of 1 million record. This was causing the error and as I fired 100 mapping jobs, it has processed the data successfully . The only thing I noticed is the time taken to complete the jobs. It has taken almost 1 hr to run all the 100 mapper jobs.

Comment: using 100 mappers makes no sense. It will surely slow your process. As you are using single node hadoop and maximum mappers than can run parallelly is less than 10 in your case. 1 million records for each mapper is a small amount.  With `Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx7200m` you should be able to perform this task with 4 mappers easily. You can drastically fast your operation. Don't use more than 4 mappers as you have 1 node cluster. Work to manage memory parameters